# PHP: Flagged Comments

Tags: php, html

I'm implementing a flag comment system on my blog, currently have this code for it:

```
<form method="POST">
<?php 
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","MyDatabase");
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, username, comment_body, user_id, DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%M %d %Y') AS date_created FROM news_comments WHERE entry_id = '" . $entry_id. "'");
 ?>
<?php while ($comment = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>
<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
  ...
  </tr>
  <td>
  <?php echo $comment['username']; ?>
  </br>
  <?php echo $comment['comment_body']; ?>
  </br>
  <?php echo $comment['date_created'];?>
  </td>
  ...
  <td>
 <button name = "report">Report</button> 

    <?php if(isset($_POST['report'])) {
    $id = $comment['id'];
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","MyDatabase");
    $sqli = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE news_comments SET isFlagged = 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    } ?>
 </td>
 ....
</table>
```

It works, but when the report button is clicked, it flags all comments on the page. How can I change this so it's just the one specific comment?

Thanks

Comment: Give the button its specific value. or add checkbox on each comments

Comment: you need to `foreach` the POST arrays and the checkbox(es) treated as an array.

Comment: I don't see CI syntax here, btw and `$entry_id` is unknown as its origin and value. Plus missing code for the form if closure exists.

Comment: You are totally missing the point of MVC.

Comment: ...and CodeIgniter/frameworks for that matter

Comment: have you checked on click of button which id is passing to php code everytime?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you have your flagging logic in the while loop. Whenever a user clicks the Report button every condition where `if(isset($_POST['report']))` is triggered - which would be all the comments.

You have to move the condition out of the loop (typically the top of the page), and then send the id of the post you want to flag as it will no longer be part of the loop.